# PHP returning a name

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to return a name from the database, but the request i did return every the names in the database.

The PHP with the request i need to perform :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "********";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "dbtest";

$FNAME = (isset($_POST['FNAME']) ? $_POST['FNAME'] :'');
// Create connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM `accounts` where FNAME = `FNAME`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s, %s<br>", $row["LNAME"], $row["FNAME"]);
    }
}

// Check connection 
if (!$conn) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "</br>Connected successfully";
?>
```

The HTML with the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="php_dbtest.php" method="POST" id="FNAME">
    Search: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="find" value="Search" id="add" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM 'accounts' where FNAME = 'FNAME' LIMIT 0,1"` will return the first name in the table you're requesting, if you have a list that means there is multiples entries with the same name.

Comment: You should check the value of the POST too.

Comment: `\`FNAME\` = '$FNAME'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT FNAME,LNAME FROM `accounts` where FNAME = '$FNAME'";
```

You need check your query with `$FNAME` variable.

And you need check `if(isset($_POST['find']){ put your query in here }`

Because your submit button click no action is working in your code now. You must need check that submit button clicked or not. If click you can go with your other codes and query.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need html declaration to the php file also. You can work with it `<?php ?>` and save your php code

Answer (score -1):

You need to change to change the quote types in the query at [image] because the backward quotes you used evaluate to `where FNAME = FNAME` which is always true and will return all the names. Also you need to use a variable in the query, as `where FNAME = '$FNAME'` because `'FNAME'` would only look for one name called `'FNAME'`.

In addition, the form is posting your input as `name` and the `id="FNAME"` on the `form` element is not considered. So you need to change your form to something like:

```
 <form action="php_dbtest.php" method="POST">
    Search: <input type="text" name="FNAME" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="find" value="Search" id="add" />
  </form>
```